# How can I learn to write audio decoding software

Tags: decoder

I decided to write a decoding software. I have chosen to deal with Vorbis and Ogg first. I've read their specification for hours, and it is a brain-screw for me. The decoding involves using bitwise operations on file's bytes, which I've rarely used in my life.

So far I understand that Ogg is a container format and Vorbis is an audio format. So it means the Vorbis data is wrapped in Ogg container? And of course, if a manage to decode a file, how can I play it?

Is there a simpler format that I can learn to decode? Also, am I right that questions about actual coding should be asked at Stackoverflow rather than here?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to start with pulse-code modulation files (.WAV, .AIFF, etc.): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-code_modulation

What is stored in a typical CD-quality PCM file is nothing more than a few metadata markers, and a trunk of stereo data kept as numbers(note, they may be floating numbers or integers).

You can view PCM files as a "dump" from the internal buffers of an audio interface. For example, when the audio interface runs at 44.1Khz/16bit, you simply read short[2][...] (because it's stereo!) from a `.wav` file and dump them into the audio interface and it will just work.

Depending on your OS/audio stack you may need different libraries for sending the "dump" into your soundcard. I had experience with https://github.com/thestk/rtaudio and it's cross-platform.

Anything beyond PCM will need a good load of math prerequisites to understand. But if you strictly follow the specs, doing every step correctly you'll be able to wrap up a decoder without understanding all the details.
You will be first decoding the stream, which effectively turns `.ogg` to `.wav` (incrementally), and throws the `.wav` segments into the audio interface.

Good luck!

Update: btw, the container-codec model is almost universal in audio/video file formats. If you dig deeper into the `WAV` format you'll find interesting stuff. :)